# Windows 10 Mail style ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-10, uwp

I'm in the process of making my first UWP App in XAML/C# (have made others in HTML/JS) so I am in a quite early learning process (so this might be an easy or hard question to answer).

But I am trying to reproduce a similar ListView to the Mail app that comes with Windows 10, I like the functionality that you can slide the list items to the left or to the right to perform an action (Archive/Flag). I was wondering if anyone knows of any resources that can help to me to replicate the same thing, or any tips where to start?

A youtube video of what I mean can be found here: https://youtu.be/AHeJyqYwK88?t=12s

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: One option might be to implement this in the DateTemplate of the ListView  Item. There for you could use an RelativePanel and include 3 Parts. And then resize the middle part when a touch movement is registered, then start showing the until know unseen part.

Comment: Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isswipeenabled) and [here](http://www.familie-smits.com/development-tips/tinder-control-for-your-windows-app)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. really useful, looking at that page gave me some new keywords to search with, and came across [this](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView) which is quite nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific question about the sliding items in a ListView

Dave Smits has created a control for this and detailed how to use it on his blog http://www.familie-smits.com/development-tips/tinder-control-for-your-windows-app
The source is up on github! Do note that this was still for WinRT wp8 and not for UWP, but I would assume it should be portable / workable in UWP too.

There is a Windows 10 UWP one available on github here https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView

Comment: I think this is what i am going to go with, would have been nice to roll my own version, but i think its more complex then i can handle for the moment. So i think i am going to give the SwipeListView a try

Comment: At least the code is there so it's a good way to pick up new things to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, at the end of this post there is a full working beautiful sample covering your needs, but before scrolling down please spent 30 seconds in reading all this.
If you are new or even intermediate with c# / XAML and Universal Windows Platform development I would recommend some basic documentation on MSDN:
 - [Design UWP apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) (MSDN)
 - [Develop UWP apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) (MSDN)
 - [Publish UWP apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/publish/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) (MSDN)
 - [What’s new for developers in Windows 10](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted/whats-new-windows-10/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) (MSDN)

Some good courses on Microsoft Virtual Academy 
 - [A Developer's Guide to Windows 10](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960)
 - [Windows 10: Getting Started with UWP](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-getting-started-with-uwp-14431/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960)
 - [XAML for Windows 10: Layout](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-layout-14328/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) 
 - [Windows 10: Developing Responsive and Adaptive UIs](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-developing-responsive-and-adaptive-uis-14584/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960)
 - [Windows 10: Data Binding](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-data-binding-14579/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960) 
 - [XAML for Windows 10: Items Controls](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-items-controls-14483?l=DXUBQwLtB_7304819052/?Wt.mc_id=dx_MVP4039960)

And last but not least Jerry Nixon's [Template 10 on GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10). It is intended for Window XAML apps written in C#, it is the brainchild of Microsoft Developer Evangelism.
Basically it is a set of comprehensive guidelines on how to develop C#/XAML UWP the right / high quality way.
If you look at the sample there is just what you are looking for: a master detail mail app style app. But before going deeper that sample please have a look to all the other links.

Hope it helps
-g

Comment: Thanks for the links, I already on second MVA course, so am aware of them, come highly recommended from me too!. And that template 10 thing, is really nice, particularly for a newcomer like me, you forgot to link it, so for others reading this, it can be found [here](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10)

Comment: Oh and one other minor thing, credit where credit is due and all that, his name is [Jerry Nixon](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/) not Jessy :)

Comment: You are right on both comments I'll update my answer also. ☺

Comment: After looking at the Master Detail sample, it has the layout, but not the swipe left/right on the items functionality i was after.